# How to create simple elevation map

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, topography, opentopomap

I'm completely new to QGIS, and I would like to know if there is a quick way of creating an elevation map as in the following example. I would like to define 4-5 altitude intervals, and color them monochromatically.

Besides doing this from scratch (by manually downloading the SRTM elevation data), is there a faster way? For example, can I change the style of the OSM or OpenTopoMap to get something similar to the style of this image?

[image: Example of elevation map style]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Mapzen Global Terrain layer which is delivered with QGIS and change the style like in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This has worked very well. Can I make the rivers visible using the Mapzen Global Terrain layer? Also, is there a smoothing function?

Comment: for rivers I would recommand a vectorlayer, for example from natural earth: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/